# Wierd faces after I moved one vertex of quads

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, loop

I am new to blender. I searched the forums for an answer to my question. I couldnt find any.

1. I loop cut a cube (vertical center)
2. I Pushed the loopcut on the Y Axis so the whole shape became like >>.
3. I pushed down the upper vertice of the head on Z axis.

This means I should get a VALLEY shape.

Problem : The side left tf the screen divides into 1 raised half and one proper half. This means i get a ^ shape bend instead of a / shape bend which joins in at the vertice. Please tell me how it can be resolved.[image: Step 1]
[[image: Step 2[][2][2]]

[image: Side appears coorect like/]

[image: Side appears wierd like \^ or like a square root symbol]

Comment: Ok man. I am new here so I didnt know. I will add in a few mins

Comment: See is it clear? Where is the Q? in blender edit mode?

Answer (score 2):

Result comes from fact that by draging only one vertex of a quad face makes face non-planar, in viewport hardly seen as two triangles (there is not any other mathematical way to result). In real life if you take plate of glass and you would take one corner lower you would have to split plate by diagonal cut between any two corners.

In your case is one face triangulated in shorter (red) direction and second in longer (green).

[image]

---

Yet not sure how final surface should looks like for you, but you can create like negative shape from two triangles and "cut" it out by **Boolean modifier > Difference** from your base mesh.

Create a new object with **two triangle** faces. Like that you keep faces planar.

[image]

For Boolean modifier you will need a *non-manifold* mesh. So extrude it by **Solidify modifier** to create one close mesh. It is non destructive way. So you can go to edit mode and adjust the "cut" shape anytime.

Now use Boolean modifier for your base object to *Difference* it.
Also I changed the viewport display mode for this object to "Wire" so you can see how Boolean modifer perform on base mesh.

[image]

[image]

Note: Blender has also an operator, you can search **Make Planar Faces**, that can recalculate them into flat faces, but in cost of distortions of all selected vertices.

Comment: Ok. So I need to increase vertices? But that wiil increase my Vertice count.

Comment: What is negative shape?

Comment: You dont need increase vertices, it depence what final shape should looks like. I edited A. If it is not what you are looking for add some mockup - image from internet that looks like you want to end-up-with or your hand scatch drawing (shaded?) from which we can see how result should looks like.

Comment: Ok man I will try and come back to you. You are a real blender person. Others avoid hard questions. How can I save this answer to desktop?